# Can not plugging in my 4 pin for my CPU affect audio?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, computer-building

I plugged in my 8pin connection for my CPU but didn't have the proper adapter for the 4pin so I just left it unplugged my pc works but the sound has dropped an octave and slowed.

Comment: It's possible, the only way to confirm, is to actual plug it in.  Without understanding what the 8-pin is exactly, which would require looking at the motherboard manual, it's really difficult to say with any degree of certainty

Comment: hahah i figured it out, when I was connecting the front USB to the motherboard it wasn't all the way in. At least I think this was it cuz when my headphones into the motherboard directly it, it fixed this haha. Im so stupid.